How can I declare my variables as public in VBA?
I am using vba for the first time in a internship, so maybe this is basic but I can't seem to make my variables public... I have tried to create a global module where I declare them as public, the ones I want to use in other places besides the UserForms where they are being used now.
I am sensing the problem is that most of them are lists so I had to set them as so, example:
Set lst = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

what I have in globalvars:
Public lst2 As Object
Public lst3 As Object
Public total As Variant
Public densl As Object
Public densal As Object
Public rtl As Object
Public cascal As Object
Public na2ol As Object
Public clo2l As Object

I have the majority of them set as I explained before, all of whom are described as objects
But if I for example run this test
Sub Example_Use_List()
    Dim i As Integer
    

    

    For i = 0 To lst2.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "Value in lst2: " & lst2(i)
    Next i


    MsgBox "The total value is: " & total
End Sub

It immediately tells me that the variable is not defined

How could an Object know what to return when doing lst2.Count  ??  (A general thing like an object does not have a count)

@Luuk Object is a generic reference to any object, resolved at run-time (aka late-binding).

Would help to show a complete example - (1) Public/Global variable declaration (2) assigning a value to the global variable and (3) using the assigned variable.  Is all of your code in regular code modules in the same workbook?  What exactly is globalvars ?  A module name?

@BigBen: But en Object need not have a Count ....

@Luuk but an ArrayList does. I think you're narrowing in on something that's not actually relevant to the question though.

That is the problem with working with Public variables.  It's hard to say where and when they are set or unset.  It is best to pass the variables as parameters.  Whenever you click Reset (Stop Button) in the VBA editor all the variables are unset.  BTW, ArrayLists are great but they are not available on all machines.

You might consider organizing all the public variables into a class.

That is the problem with working with Public variables. It's hard to say where and when they are set or unset. It is best to pass the variables as parameters. Whenever you click Reset (Stop Button) in the VBA editor all the variables are unset. BTW, ArrayLists are great but they are not available on all machines.
There is no enough context to know exactly what is wrong.  Checking to see if the object is set is the best that I can do.
Option Explicit

Public lst2 As Object
Public lst3 As Object
Public Total As Variant
Public densl As Object
Public densal As Object
Public rtl As Object
Public cascal As Object
Public na2ol As Object
Public clo2l As Object

Sub lst2_InitExample()
    Set lst2 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To 20
        lst2.Add n
    Next
End Sub

Sub Example_Use_List()
    Dim n As Long
    Dim Total As Double
    
    ' Check if lst2 is Nothing before proceeding
    If lst2 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "lst2 is not initialized.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each item in lst2 and print its value in the Immediate Window
    For n = 0 To lst2.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "Value in lst2: " & lst2(n)
    Next

    ' Convert lst2 to an array and sum its values
    Total = Application.Sum(lst2.ToArray)
    
    ' Display the total value in a message box
    MsgBox "The total value is: " & Total
End Sub

